# Is there a program like GitLab written in Python?

Tags: python

I want to use private git repositories hosted on our web server, for which I am in search of a program like GitLab written in Python. I am in search of a program which is written in python and no other language. Also it would be great if that program can provide UI similar to Github or Gitlab.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem already? I saw you did not accept any answer, so.

Answer (score 3):

There is [klaus](https://github.com/jonashaag/klaus) but I don't know how feature full it is

[image: klaus 1]
[image: klaus 2]

you could also use Trac with git but I'm not sure you'd like it.

What are your concerns about ruby(or java/.net/php/etc.)? Do you plan to substantially extend these applications yourself? Have you had troubles hosting ruby web apps before?
Are you worried about about rails specific security problems(which don't only occur in rails) because some ruby git front ends are written in sinatra not rails.

Comment: We use Django and we don't want to configure a different technology stack for git hosting. Since we want to host private repositories on our server, we want it to be in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this great module special made for python

https://github.com/gpocentek/python-gitlab

it's fairly new, so updates will come soon.

**EDIT:**

Just look at this website, there are a lot alternatives that will also work in python.

http://alternativeto.net/software/gitlab/

Comment: I have seen that, the thing is I don't want to use ruby on rails any where.

Comment: why did you not mention that in your question? and the tag says ruby.

Comment: see my edit. hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my question.

Comment: python-gitlab is NOT an alternative. Is is just a wrapper around GitLab's API.